# Comma Separator - ACT

Tags: grammar, writing

As I was preparing for the ACT, I came across this question:

Phrase: "Key and Peele is at its best when it deals with questions of
what is expected of mixed-race people, in a society reluctant
to let go of racial stereotypes"

Is that right? Or is the phrase below correct:

Key and Peele is at its best when it deals with questions of
what is expected of mixed-race people in a society reluctant
to let go of racial stereotypes" (No comma before in a society)

If so, why? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you wouldn't  have a comma before a prepositional phrase at the end of a sentence, eg. He got up in the morning. She got it done in the nick of time.
If you do use a comma, it has an effect similar to a dash -- in that it makes you pause and gives the part after the dash some extra emphasis.